# How do you say "He was looking for you" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

I have a colleague X, and another person from the office named Y came looking for him but X was not on his seat. When X comes back, how do I tell him "Y came looking for you"?

Comment: Did you try to use an online translator? What did it say? Do you have further problems with this translation attempt?

Comment: reopened as per meta https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/why-should-somebody-consult-an-online-translation-service-before-asking-here

Answer (score 7):

Formal would be

> Y hat Dich/Sie gesucht.
>   Y hat nach Dir/Ihnen gefragt.

You could also say (informally)

> Y wollte Dich sprechen
>   Y war gerade hier
>   Y wollte was von Dir

Answer (score 2):

#### formal:

> Frau Y hat Sie gesucht.
> Y hat Dich gesucht.

#### informal:

> Y wollte etwas von Dir.

The level of formality in your office somewhat decides what to use but you never go wrong with the formal variant.

Comment: This only goes to show that the initial eager to close this question were wrong. I could never have guessed that the phrase with "wollte" is informal, nor can I find this info in the usual resources.

Comment: @Beta: thank you - that is exactly why I brought it up in Meta.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the level of formality your colleagues talk to each other and talk to you. Listed from the the language you would use with a friend to very polite and formal language, these would be my solutions:

> Y wollte was von Dir/Ihnen

This is the equivalent of: "X wanted something". As you see, it is not the politest language, but it most definitely isn't rude.

> Y hat Dich/Sie gesucht

> Y war vorhin hier

> Y wollte etwas mit Dir/Ihnen besprechen

> Y hatte ein Anliegen

These are just simple sentences, you could add more details like "Y wanted to talk to you, but you weren't here, so I said I'd remind you", I don't know if that's the case